Jenkins pipeline not able to find xmlReportPaths
while trying to add the jacoco coverage report to sonarqube, for my multimodule java project (maven). The report was not showing on the sonarqube dashboard.
After checking the logs I found this warning:
[WARNING] 12:17:12.185 No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='code-coverage-report/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

I found this link facing the same issue but without a solution.

adding the full path of the file was able to resolve my issue.
instead of:
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='code-coverage-report/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml'

use:
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/mts/UTILITIES/MTS-ARCHIVAL-REFRESH/COVERAGE_REPORT_REFRESHER/uiTestsRepo/code-coverage-report/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml'

